# My android app closes unexpectedly. Eclipse says it can't connect to the local host

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

I'm creating an android application. It compiles well and eclipse does not spot any errors. However when I run it I get this in the stack trace.

```
<disconnected>DalvikVM[localhost:8639]
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.warhammerdicerrolleralpha;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myMain extends Activity 
{

    EditText enternumberofdice;

    TextView textGenerateNumber;

    int number1;

    int number2;

    ImageView i;

    private EditText text, text2, text3;

    private Button btutorial1;

    private int myFaceValue;

    int myNum;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);

        number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

        number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());

        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);

        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    }

    public void go() 
    {
        while (myNum > 0) 
        {

            textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(enternumberofdice));

             --myNum;

            return;
        }
    }

    public int roll() 
    {
        int val = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1); // Range 1-6
        setValue(val);
        return val;
    }

    {
        try 
        {
            myNum = Integer.parseInt(enternumberofdice.getText().toString());
        } 
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
        {
            enternumberofdice.setText("Does not work");
        }
    }

    public int getValue() 
    {
        return myFaceValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int myFaceValue) 
    {
        this.myFaceValue = myFaceValue;

    }

    {
        switch (myFaceValue) 
        {
        case 5:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefive);
            break;
        case 1:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceone);
            break;
        case 3:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicethree);
            break;
        case 2:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicetwo);
            break;
        case 4:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefour);
            break;
        case 6:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicesix);
            break;
        default:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
            break;
        }

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        text2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);  

        btutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btutorial1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        enternumberofdice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enternumberofdice);

        Button buttonGenerate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.battlecalculate);

        buttonGenerate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()    
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            }

        });

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()     
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                go();

                roll();
            }

        });
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        switch (view.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.button1:

                if (number1 > number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Three and above");       
                    return;
                }

                else if (number1 < number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Five and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else if (number1 == number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Four and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    text3.setText("Not Working");       
                    return;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

P.S. How do you add xml code to your post. When I add xml code to my post, it doesn't appear in the preview page.

Here is my stack trace.

DalvikVM[localhost:8695]
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2585
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679
        ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
    Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running)

Comment: To add XML to your question, simply paste the XML in, select it, and click the icon above the editor that looks like this: `{}`. You should do the same thing for any code snippet that needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class-level variable initialization you do, e.g. `textGenerateNumber`, must be done *after* the call to to `setContentView` in the `onCreate` method.

**Update:** restructuring the code you should have something like this. Though, the `number1` and `number2` assignments doesn't make sense since you haven't initialized the `text` and `text2` variables.

```
....

EditText enternumberofdice;
TextView textGenerateNumber;
private EditText text, text2, text3;
private Button btutorial1;
int number1;
int number2;
ImageView i;
private int myFaceValue;
int myNum;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);

    //BUG: will fail since text/text2 isn't initialized
    //number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
    //number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());

    i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
}
```

Comment: Okay so your saying move textGenerateNumber after onCreate method?.

Comment: Okay I did what you said and now I get a The local variable textGenerateNumber is never read. However that shouldn't it be because  I added TextView textGenerateNumber; to the top.

Comment: Why did you convert the integers in the OnCreate class?   and this change the page?. public void onClick(View v) 
   {
     setContentView(R.layout.main2);
   }

Comment: I'm stilling getting errors give a me sec to tell you my stack trace.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to initialize number1 and number2 and the activity startup. If this doesn't make sense you should remove it. Bottom line is, you cannot execute layout related code until after the `onCreate` method have been executed and content is initialized with the `setContentView` method.

Comment: Can you take a look at my stack trace, it up on were my original post is.

Comment: Have your code ever worked? I suggest you backtrack. There's just to many places the code could crash, it will be hard for me to spot without being able to debug the code. But note, as I'll change my sample now, the `number1` and `number2` assignments will crash the app since the text views are not initialized anywhere.

Comment: I'm a college student new to programming. Most of my programs work, because simple math project. I'm learning

Comment: I understand, we all start out somewhere :) A good tip is to go on the web and look at other samples, read the code and try to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
```

is run before the `onCreate` method so your views don't exist yet. Add all code to retrieve views after your call to `setContentView()`.

Comment: I get a The local variable textGenerateNumber is never read. However that should not be because TextView textGenerateNumber; is in the parent

Comment: When that isn't in a method it gets called when the object is created.